# chakra UI - vertical alignment at top

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, chakra-ui

Using chakra UI, I have a two column layout.
I want all the items to be aligned at the top.

For some reason they are aligning in the center...
I'm using this markup:

```
 <HStack verticalAlign='top' height='100%' position='relative' className='debug-blue'>
    <VStack spacing={2} width={marginSize} height={marginHeight} className='sidebar debug-red'>
        {listWallets()}
    </VStack>

    <VStack align='flex-start' alignItems='flex-start' verticalAlign='top' >
        {/* {showPieces()} */}
        {dummyBlocks()}
    </VStack>

</HStack>
```

this is the problem line:

`<VStack align='flex-start' alignItems='flex-start' verticalAlign='top' >`

but see this image where the items in the blue box get VCentered.

I got the items at right to align with a `top: 0` CSS tag, which seems like a real hack.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran in to this and this answer came up. Even though it seems very old, I will add what worked for me for future reference:

Try converting the HStack to a Flex component. Here's an example:

```
<Flex minHeight="100vh" bg={"blue.700"}>
  <VStack spacing={2} bg={"red.200"}>
    <Text>test2</Text>
    <Text>test3</Text>
  </VStack>

  <VStack bg={"green.200"}>
    {/* {showPieces()} */}
    <Text>test2</Text>
    <Text>test3</Text>
  </VStack>
</Flex>
```

Hopefully that helps in the future